# Xamarin Android on Jenkins ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, jenkins, xamarin, mono

Is it possible to build Xamarin.Android projects on Jenkins server running on ubuntu ?

I've been able to install mono packages but there is no sign of the Xamarin dependencies. The error I get is the following :

`Droid/Droid.csproj: error : could not import "$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets"`

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin only supports Windows and OS X.